# "Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression" in MS-Access SQL

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

The MS-Access SQL Query below returns a `"Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression"` error

```
SELECT DateSerial(2016,Month(DOB),Day(DOB)) AS AnnDate
FROM DonorMaster WHERE  DateSerial(2016,Month(DOB),Day(DOB)) > Date()
```

When run without the `">"` operator it runs correctly and all the returned rows have data.

What should be done to fix the error?

Comment: Which data type of [DOB] field? If date, SQL should work fine

Comment: Check for DOB's that are NULL and adjust your query accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table most likely consists null values for one or more DOB's.
This will throw the error.
Redesign your query, for instance like this:

```
SELECT DateSerial(2016,Month(Nz(DOB, Date())),Day(Nz(DOB, Date()))) AS AnnDate
FROM DonorMaster 
WHERE DateSerial(2016,Month(Nz(DOB, Date())),Day(Nz(DOB, Date()))) >Date();
```

Comment: There were NULL values in the table. Thanks.